# Adding an EditIndex to a Panel in Gridview Edit: can't set because the property doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web-controls

Error:

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' does not contain a definition for
>   'EditIndex' and no extension method 'EditIndex' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code:

```
protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        pnlGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: yeah, how to fix that issue?? please suggest me

Comment: You can't set a property that doesn't exist.  It's *not there*.  That's what the error says.  To remove the error, remove that line of code.

Comment: then how to edit grid using panel..??

Comment: My HTML code is: <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlGrid" Visible="true" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowDeleting ="delete"  OnRowUpdating = "Update">
                <div class="customscroll table-responsive">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have put a Panel reference instead of a [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex(v=vs.110).aspx) reference.

**[edit]**

Example:

```
<asp:GridView id="theGrid" runat="server" Visible="true" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowDeleting ="delete" OnRowUpdating = "Update" />
```

and `OnRowEditing` to access the grid:

```
theGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
```

So, you are accessing a GridView, not a Panel which is a "static" control.

Comment: I changed to Panel reference..but its showing same error!